# javascript implementing problem in creating a ms teams app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, microsoft-teams

I am new at creating Microsoft Apps and i managed to build an app (**group tab**) and install it in Teams.

How can i attach an external javascript file to the **Tab.js**?

> import './MyFunction.js';      //get's ignored

How can i generally use javascript code in the **Tab.js** , because it wont even accept the **script tag** without returning an error?
[Compile with Script - ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is8Ud.png)

(The only thing i found out was that you need the **javascript client sdk**, but i cannot find examples or how/where to you use it in the Tab Script)

Comment: To attach one javascript file in another javascript in your example you need to export Myfunction in Myfunction.js and import Myfunction from './Myfunction.js' in Tab.js.
For second question you cannot use script tag in Tab.js, in return() function you need to write html code and in render() function you need write functions you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

To attach one javascript file in another javascript in your example you need to export Myfunction in Myfunction.js and import Myfunction from './Myfunction.js' in Tab.js. For second question you cannot use script tag in Tab.js, in return() function you need to write html code and in render() function you need write functions you want to call.